# Display Media Uploader in Own Plugin on Wordpress 3.5

Tags: forms, wordpress, media, uploader

I have little problem with Media Uploader in new WordPress 3.5. I created own plugin which is upload the picture. I'm using this code JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var file_frame;

    jQuery('.button-secondary').live('click', function( event ){

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( file_frame ) {
            file_frame.open();
            return;
        }

        file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media(
            {
                title: 'Select File',
                button: {
                    text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' )
                },
                multiple: false
            }
        );

        file_frame.on('select', function() {
            attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
            jQuery('#IMGsrc').val(attachment.url);
        });

        file_frame.open();
    });
</script>
```

The code works fine, but unfortunately forms appears incomplete. When I select any picture doesn't show me 'Attachment Display Settings' on right side. I don't know why. I try add options to media:

```
displaySettings: true,
displayUserSettings: true
```

But it also doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing and all the research shows the same thing but no one explaining anything about showing the attachment settings option... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540951/custom-wp-media-with-arguments-support

Answer (score 0):

Does the page have the `<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-attachment-details">...` template in the source? If not, you'll need to call wp_print_media_templates(), to write the styles from wp-includes/media-template.php

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use.  Source: http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/  It seems to work pretty well, but the sidebar on the left is missing. (Intentional, but I don't want it anyways).

```
<?php wp_enqueue_media(); ?>

<script>

function showAddPhotos() {

// Uploading files
var file_frame;

// event.preventDefault();

// If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
if ( file_frame ) {
  file_frame.open();
  return;
}

// Create the media frame.
file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
  title: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_title' ),
  button: {
    text: jQuery( this ).data( 'uploader_button_text' ),
  },
  multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
});

// When an image is selected, run a callback.
file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
  // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
  attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

  // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
});

// Finally, open the modal
file_frame.open();

}
</script>
```