# Custom wp.media with arguments support

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-media

How to setup a [add media] button, with:

1. proper wordpress [media] UI
2. has size and alignments UI in popup right hand side
3. can custom popup title and button
4. size and alignments arguments can send back to be use

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just try to cover most solutions:

1. use `tb_show("", "media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true");` and `window.send_to_editor`

   - problem: has no standard wp.media UI
   - in js code:

     ```
     jQuery("#my_button").click(function() {
         tb_show("", "media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true");
         return false;
     });
     window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
         console.log(html);
         tb_remove();
     }
     ```
2. use `wp.media({frame: 'post'})`

   - problem: cannot custom UI elements, such as: title, button
   - in js code:

     ```
     function clearField(){
         #remove file nodes
         #...
     }

     var frame = wp.media({frame: 'post'});

     frame.on('close',function() {
         var selection = frame.state().get('selection');
         if(!selection.length){
             clearField();
         }
     });

     frame.on( 'select',function() {
         var state = frame.state();
         var selection = state.get('selection');
         if ( ! selection ) return;

         clearField();

         selection.each(function(attachment) {
             console.log(attachment.attributes);
         });
     });

     frame.open();
     ```
3. use `wp.media.editor` with `wp.media.editor.open( editor_id )`

   - problem: cannot custom UI elements, such as: title, button
   - in js code: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75808/using-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-meta-box#75823
4. use `wp.media` with rewrite `wp.media.controller.Library` and retrieve `attachment` in `select`

   - problem: complicated ..., but once you understand it, it all make sense, and it is my finial solution
   - in js code:

     ```
     /**
      * Please attach all the code below to a button click event
      **/

     //create a new Library, base on defaults
     //you can put your attributes in
     var insertImage = wp.media.controller.Library.extend({
         defaults :  _.defaults({
                 id:        'insert-image',
                 title:      'Insert Image Url',
                 allowLocalEdits: true,
                 displaySettings: true,
                 displayUserSettings: true,
                 multiple : true,
                 type : 'image'//audio, video, application/pdf, ... etc
           }, wp.media.controller.Library.prototype.defaults )
     });

     //Setup media frame
     var frame = wp.media({
         button : { text : 'Select' },
         state : 'insert-image',
         states : [
             new insertImage()
         ]
     });

     //on close, if there is no select files, remove all the files already selected in your main frame
     frame.on('close',function() {
         var selection = frame.state('insert-image').get('selection');
         if(!selection.length){
             #remove file nodes
             #such as: jq("#my_file_group_field").children('div.image_group_row').remove();
             #...
         }
     });


     frame.on( 'select',function() {
         var state = frame.state('insert-image');
         var selection = state.get('selection');
         var imageArray = [];

         if ( ! selection ) return;

         #remove file nodes
         #such as: jq("#my_file_group_field").children('div.image_group_row').remove();
         #...

         //to get right side attachment UI info, such as: size and alignments
         //org code from /wp-includes/js/media-editor.js, arround `line 603 -- send: { ... attachment: function( props, attachment ) { ... `
         selection.each(function(attachment) {
             var display = state.display( attachment ).toJSON();
             var obj_attachment = attachment.toJSON()
             var caption = obj_attachment.caption, options, html;

             // If captions are disabled, clear the caption.
             if ( ! wp.media.view.settings.captions )
                 delete obj_attachment.caption;

             display = wp.media.string.props( display, obj_attachment );

             options = {
                 id:        obj_attachment.id,
                 post_content: obj_attachment.description,
                 post_excerpt: caption
             };

             if ( display.linkUrl )
                 options.url = display.linkUrl;

             if ( 'image' === obj_attachment.type ) {
                 html = wp.media.string.image( display );
                 _.each({
                 align: 'align',
                 size:  'image-size',
                 alt:   'image_alt'
                 }, function( option, prop ) {
                 if ( display[ prop ] )
                     options[ option ] = display[ prop ];
                 });
             } else if ( 'video' === obj_attachment.type ) {
                 html = wp.media.string.video( display, obj_attachment );
             } else if ( 'audio' === obj_attachment.type ) {
                 html = wp.media.string.audio( display, obj_attachment );
             } else {
                 html = wp.media.string.link( display );
                 options.post_title = display.title;
             }

             //attach info to attachment.attributes object
             attachment.attributes['nonce'] = wp.media.view.settings.nonce.sendToEditor;
             attachment.attributes['attachment'] = options;
             attachment.attributes['html'] = html;
             attachment.attributes['post_id'] = wp.media.view.settings.post.id;

             //do what ever you like to use it
             console.log(attachment.attributes);
             console.log(attachment.attributes['attachment']);
             console.log(attachment.attributes['html']);
         });
     });

     //reset selection in popup, when open the popup
     frame.on('open',function() {
         var selection = frame.state('insert-image').get('selection');

         //remove all the selection first
         selection.each(function(image) {
             var attachment = wp.media.attachment( image.attributes.id );
             attachment.fetch();
             selection.remove( attachment ? [ attachment ] : [] );
         });

         //add back current selection, in here let us assume you attach all the [id] to <div id="my_file_group_field">...<input type="hidden" id="file_1" .../>...<input type="hidden" id="file_2" .../>
         jq("#my_file_group_field").find('input[type="hidden"]').each(function(){
              var input_id = jq(this);
             if( input_id.val() ){
                 attachment = wp.media.attachment( input_id.val() );
                 attachment.fetch();
                 selection.add( attachment ? [ attachment ] : [] );
             }
         });
     });

     //now open the popup
     frame.open();
     ```

Comment: Option 4 was what I was looking for when trying to add an additional image upload in a meta box for a custom post type with editor enabled.
Do you happen to know if there's any documentation for `wp.media`? I've looked a lot online and couldn't find anything complete and I've resorted to reading the base js file defining this object.

Comment: Hi. I don't know if you're still working with wp.media in wordpress framework. Unfortunately there isn't a fully documentation to let advanced developers to using it properly. I just found this plugin https://github.com/ericandrewlewis/wp-media-javascript-guide that point out the mai features of wp.media objects. But i'm still looking for a very fully documentation to understand each component of wp.media.

Comment: I like this function.. for number 4.. but how I can insert it to input

`<input type="text" name="user_meta_image" id="user_meta_image" value="<?php echo esc_url_raw( get_the_author_meta( 'user_meta_image', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />`

or maybe I need to add different id to my input

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add to ZAC's option 4 because when I used his code, the image src="" was missing.

Here is the fix

```
                if ( 'image' === obj_attachment.type ) {
                html = wp.media.string.image( display );
                _.each({
                align: 'align',
                size:  'image-size',
                alt:   'image_alt'
                }, function( option, prop ) {
                if ( display[ prop ] )
                    options[ option ] = display[ prop ];
                });
                html = wp.media.string.image( display, obj_attachment );
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

This way you can call the new media uploader with custom title and button and right side bar.

```
var custom_uploader;
jQuery('#fileform').on('click','.select-files', function(e) {
    var button = jQuery(this);
    custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: 'Choose File',
        library: {
            author: userSettings.uid // specific user-posted attachment
        },
        button: {
            text: 'Choose File'
        },
        multiple: false
    });

    //When a file is selected, grab the URL and set it as the text field's value
    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
        attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
        console.log(attachment.url);
        console.log(attachment.id); // use them the way you want
    });

    //Open the uploader dialog
    // Set post id
    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = jQuery('#post_ID').val();
    custom_uploader.open();
});
```

Comment: `author: userSettings.uid` This seems to not specific user only. It show media for all users.

Comment: I worked on this problem for days until I saw your solution. It wasn't exactly what i needed but one line of your code solved my problem: wp.media.model.settings.post.id Plus 1!

Answer (score 0):

Check this link -> https://github.com/phpcodingmaster/WordPress-Media-Modal-Image-Uploads

It will show you how to:

- Open the admin media modal
- Get single image info
- Get multiple images info

Tested with WordPress Version 6.0

Comment: Hi, I'm having a little issue with this approach, When I first open the wp.media modal, the thumbs for the images are missing. It will only appear if a click on upload tab and then back to Media Library again. Do you have any Idea how to fix it?

Comment: Since this was a recent post, I was really hoping it would demonstrate how to do it using vanilla JS, but looks like everyone still using jQuery.