# Wordpress custom shortcode editor [BackboneJS & TinyMCE)

Tags: wordpress, backbone.js, tinymce, editor

I'm using Wordpress 3.9.1 and I wrote a custom shortcode that working, but I'd like to custom it a little bit
When I use my shortcode, this is the render in the admin page :

```
[toggles title="zaez"]aezaezae[/toggles]
```

I can edit, add text or link to the text "aezaezae".
And i'd like to keep this behavior but make it more good to look.

So I used some code from wordpress (gallery's code) and did that :

```
(function($) {

    var views = {},
        instances = {},
        media = wp.media,
        viewOptions = ['encodedText'];

    // Create the `wp.mce` object if necessary.
    wp.mce = wp.mce || {};

    wp.mce.toggles = {
        shortcode: 'toggles',
        toView: function(content) {
            var match = wp.shortcode.next(this.shortcode, content);

            if (!match) {
                return;
            }

            return {
                index: match.index,
                content: match.content,
                options: {
                    shortcode: match.shortcode
                }
            };
        },
        View: wp.mce.View.extend({
            className: 'editor-toggles',
            template: media.template('editor-toggles'),

            // The fallback post ID to use as a parent for galleries that don't
            // specify the `ids` or `include` parameters.
            //
            // Uses the hidden input on the edit posts page by default.
            postID: $('#post_ID').val(),

            initialize: function(options) {
                this.shortcode = options.shortcode;
            },

            getHtml: function() {
                var attrs = this.shortcode.attrs.named,
                    content = this.shortcode.content,
                    options;

                options = {
                    content: content,
                    title: attrs.title
                };

                return this.template(options);

            }
        })

    };
    wp.mce.views.register('toggles', wp.mce.toggles);
}(jQuery));
```

And this is the template that is called

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl-editor-toggles">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="dashicons dashicons-edit edit"></div><div class="dashicons dashicons-no-alt remove"></div>
    </div>
    <# if ( data.title ) { #>

            <h2>{{ data.title }}</h2>
            <hr>
            <p data-wpview-pad="1">{{ data.content }}</p>
            <hr>

    <# } #>
</script>
```

It's working too, but at this time I cannot edit my content anymore. I looked with the gallery's function, but it called another window (`wp.media.gallery`), and I'd like to be able to edit in this default editor...

Can someone tell me if it's possible and maybe give me a clue ?
I found this but like I said it's for media (images... videos)
[Custom wp.media with arguments support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540951/custom-wp-media-with-arguments-support)

If I've to call a new window to edit my shortcode I'll do it but I don't really know how..

Thanks you !
Best regards
Thomas

Comment: How did you finally managed this ? Here, you are creating a Mce View, that is not editable (this is the intended behavior). You should provide edit tools inside the view (like replacing the text with an `<input>` element and controlling edits via JavaScript).

Comment: possible duplicate of [contenteditable single-line input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831482/contenteditable-single-line-input)

Answer (score -3):

There's a great article on creating shortcodes here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/

Scroll down to the section titled "Shortcode TinyMCE Editor Button" and you'll see an example of what I think you're trying to do.

> When we press the shortcode button, a dialog appears that prompts us
>   to type the shortcode parameter