# Wordpress: wp.media.frame doesn't display attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the wp.media frame uploader in my plugin to upload files. It works perfectly as it should except one problem. 
When I upload file (using upload button, or drag and drop) it uploads the file and displays its information in sidebar menu, but doesn't display thumbnail of attachment. Its a kind of annoying problem because first its a default behaviour on wp.media and second same implementation is working fine on different plugin. Has anyone come across this problem..

Code I used is:

```
    var alex_doc_uploader = $thisButton.data('file_frame');
    if (alex_doc_uploader) {
        alex_doc_uploader.open();
        return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    alex_doc_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: "Select Documents",
        button: {
            text: "Select Documents"
        },
        library : {
          type:   accepted_mime_types
        },
        multiple: true  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });

    $thisButton.data('file_frame', alex_doc_uploader);
```

And when i upload a file, 
[image]

The result I get is 
[image]

But what should happen is
[image]

Comment: https://vrajeshdave.wordpress.com/2015/06/05/how-to-use-default-media-upload-in-plugin-page/

Comment: @vrajesh : I am following the same concept  and it works but the problem is not displaying thumbnail when uploaded. Its a default behaviour as I understand. So I wonder what is that I am missing to wp.media is not functioning as it should.

Comment: hey you are uploading document file ....how can we create thumbnail of document file...?

Comment: By thumbnail I mean Icon of document.. Like the one that is on screen.. When I reopen the media uploader, I can see that document.. but not right away when I upload..

Comment: u mean when reopen the media upload all file you had uploaded would be selected?

Comment: @vrajesh I have added more detail..

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187611/display-media-uploader-in-own-plugin-on-wordpress-3-5

Comment: you need to add function file_frame.on('select', function() {

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.. It was a bug on wordpress till 4.2.2. Wordpress can't support multiple mimetypes provided as type of wp.media. It does support to filter out the content displayed but can't load on screen if uploaded. 
Here is the issue created on wordpress

[Media Upload mimeType validation bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32746)

[My patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/32746/32746.patch)

hopefully it will be solved in 4.2.3 or 4.3. Or you can do patch with those patches